# java concatenate string and command, and command string join, can someone help me?

Tags: java, string

I need to join a variable in a command and I am not able to do that.

This variable will change constantly, so I have to do it this way.

Could anyone help me?

example:

So it works perfectly:

```
System.out.println (UsersEmail.get(i).GetEmailMaria());
```

But still can not make it work:

```
System.out.println (UsersEmail.get (i).GetEmail + Email);
```

Below the code.

```
String Email = getEmailUser(); // the output would be: Maria()
for(int i = 0; i < UsersEmail.size(); i++){  
    System.out.println(UsersEmail.get(i).getEmail+Email);   
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that getEmail (or GetEmail) is a data member?  Should it have () after it?   GetEmail() ?

Comment: In simpler words getEmail is a method not a variable. It needs to include () or (parameter variable(s)) to call the method.

Comment: The contents of the string needs to be part of the command, is that part will be changed at any moment

Answer (score 0):

Try using string empty between them.

```
System.out.println(UsersEmail.get(i).getEmail + "" + Email);
```

Comment: Hello Orel, did not work because he did not run the command as a whole, performed a piece after the other

entidade.UsersEmail[ id=7801 ].Maria()